# How can i have a clear icon in the primeNg input?

Tags: primeng

Need to put a clear icon inside text box of primeNg. And on click it should clear the field.

Answer (score 4):

For PrimeNG version 11

It's easy, just modify the sample code provided in the documentation slightly to add (click).

component.html

```
<span class="p-input-icon-right">
    <i class="pi pi-times-circle" (click)="clearfilter()" ></i>
    <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="value2" >        
</span>
```

component.ts

```
clearFilter() {
this.value2 = '';
}
```

component.css

```
.pi.pi-times-circle {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the class p-input-icon-right like this:

```
<span class="p-input-icon-right">
    <input
        #inputDuration
        type="text"
        pInputText
        [(ngModel)]="duration"
    />
    <i 
        *ngIf="inputDuration.value" 
        class="pi pi-times cursor-pointer" 
        (click)="inputDuration.value = null;"
    ></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Primefaces

```
<div class="ui-inputgroup">

   <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i>
   </span>

  <input type="text" [value]="search_text" placeholder="Search" #texttosearch (keyup)="onKey(texttosearch.value)" pInputText>

   <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times" (click)="texttosearch.value = ''"></i>
   </span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is more related to CSS. Anyways I hope you are looking for something like this.

**Below Code will show the icon at the right side, inside Primeng text box:**

```
<input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Username">  
        <span style="margin-left:-20px;">
            <button (click)="userclick()" style="border:none; outline: none; position: relative; width:0;background-color: #fff;">
                <i class="pi pi-times"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
```

**If you want to see the icon in left side, inside the text box:**
Then use the span before input type and adjust the margin.

I am using inline CSS just to serve your purpose. But I highly recommend make a class
and use these properties there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -->

```
 <input
                        type="text"
                        pInputText
                        placeholder="Type Text"
                        [(ngModel)]="text"
                        (input)="someText($event.target.value)"
                        style="width:auto"

                    />
                    <span style="margin-left:-20px;">
                        <a (click)="clearText()">
                            <i class="fa fa-times" style="color: rgb(149, 149, 153); cursor: pointer;"></i>
                        </a>
                    </span>
```